# (JS) How can I get a Telegram user's ID that has been replied?

Tags: javascript, telegram

I have got a '/status' command, that should show user's data when you reply his message. For example:

```
User1: random text
User2: /status [reply to user 1]
Bot: User 1's data: ...
```

How can I make it with Telegram Bot API (JS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getUserId = (message) => {
  if (message.reply_to_message) {
    return message.reply_to_message.from.id;
  }
  return message.from.id;
};
```